# Not able to access my tomcat from remote system

Tags: apache, tomcat, webserver, lan, remote-server

I have a tomcat server running in my local machine and i am able to access the tomcat default page in my local browser using the URL htpp://ip-addres:9999/.

When i try the same from another machine i am getting page not fond error .

Both are on same workgroup : GGblackgroup

when i try pinging the machine name (657virtual93) it resolves into  **657virtual93.GGblackgroup.bbgh.com [10.245.241.47]**

i am able to ping successfully from both machine  vice versa . please let me know if am doing something wrong here .

If i am able to ping a system i should be able access the server too rite ?

Comment: - Have you checked that the firewall is configured correctly? - Another thing to test quickly is the kind of response that you get - is it just dead, or do you get some sort of connection to tomcat? /Willems

Comment: for sure it is not reaching the tomcat server. the logs report nothing; In case firewall is there is a way to check whether the firewall is blocking it ? i have no access to the firewall

Comment: It seems you have access to the mahcine, so asserting that you are in a windows environment, I would check the local firewall(Windows Firewall).
Too see if its open, you could maybe run a port scan?
How are your machines connected? That would be awesome information. :-)